# Convert query from MySQL to Oracle using MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, oracle-text

I really need help with the below query written in MySQL I want to convert in Oracle pl/sql. I read some Oracle text document and I suppose that for `MATCH AGAINST` in MySQL I can use `CONTAINS` in Oracle, but I have a problem converting the columns score, score0 and score1.

```
SELECT table_id,
       MATCH(text) AGAINST('grand hotel') AS score,
       MATCH(text) AGAINST('grand') AS score0,
       MATCH(text) AGAINST('hotel') AS score1 
  FROM tbl
 WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('grand hotel')
 ORDER BY score ASC
```

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the documentation you refer in your question is [Oracle Text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/toc.htm) and that you're already somewhat familiar with the feature. You also give no reason why PL/SQL should be involved so below is a simple plain SQL example that should address your question:

**The data**

```
create table so32 as
select 1 as id, 'Lorem grand ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras faucibus.' as text from dual union all
select 2 as id, 'Lorem ipsum hotel dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras faucibus.' as text from dual union all
select 3 as id, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, grand consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras faucibus.' as text from dual union all
select 4 as id, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur hotel adipiscing elit. Cras faucibus.' as text from dual union all
select 5 as id, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit grand. Cras faucibus.' as text from dual union all
select 6 as id, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet grand hotel, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras faucibus.' as text from dual
;
```

**Oracle Text index**

```
create index so32_index on so32(text) indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

**The query**

```
select id, 
       score(1) as grand,
       score(2) as hotel,
       score(3) as grandhotel
  from so32
 where contains(text, 'grand', 1) > 0
    or contains(text, 'hotel', 2) > 0
    or contains(text, 'grand hotel', 3) > 0
 order by score(3), score(2), score(1)
;
```

**Results**

```
        ID      GRAND      HOTEL GRANDHOTEL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4          0          0
         3          4          0          0
         5          4          0          0
         4          0          4          0
         2          0          4          0
         6          4          4          4

6 rows selected.
```

Hope this helps !